# S.O.S Monitor Says No signal and HDMI inactive to Raspberry Pi4B

Tags: hdmi, screen, config.txt

I connected mi PI4B to the monitor with HDMI-MicroHDMI adapter, and when I power de PI device, the monitor says "HDMI Inactive" and no signal. The screen was in black. The Red led of the PI is alway On and the red one is blinking and later(around 3-4minutes) turn Off.
I tried to install Raspbian in other SD, and modify the "config.txt"
In the config I tried to uncommment:

```
hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=4
```

But it didnt works, someone could help me please?

My monitor is: HP24fh (1920*1080):
https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07HH85ZFD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

And the adapter Hdmi to MicroHdmi:
https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07K21HSQX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I used Raspberry PI4B (kit of LABSTS):
https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07XLK59Z3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Many thanks

Comment: Do you know that the connecting cable is good? Can you connect to the pi using SSH?

Answer (score 0):

The Pi should automatically connect to the monitor without having to change anything.

Are you connecting to the correct HDMI port on the Pi? It's the one closest to the power jack.

Do you know that the connecting cable is good? Can you connect to the Pi using SSH?

Comment: Hi BobT, I don´t Know why the Pi are not conected automatically, it's strange. Yes, I connected the HDMI to the principal port. I can´t connected vía SSH because I think I need to configurate the Raspberry first to access to the comand line. I don't know what the fault can be. Many thanks for your quickly reply